# Find a file activity

Tags: filesystem, 15.10, log

I need to find what are all files opened yesterday in my system.I didn't installed GNOME activity. Is there any way i can see the activity a file when are all  a file opened and how many times accessed.

Comment: You mean accessed via GUI or *at all*?

Comment: File access time can be displayed with stat, but there's no "history" that can be displayed for when and how many times a file as opened. At least not to my knowledge

Comment: only gui there is a text file which i need to whether it is opened yesterday.

Comment: You mean *literally* yesterday, or in general? Yesterday is impossible I believe. From now on getting "yesterday's activity" on a file, opened via gui should be possible. Your comment seems to clash with the latest edit (accepted by you) by the way. Roll back?

Comment: Edit it is a mistake i did ,see same name rather than logging in with stack  exchange occidentally  logged in with gmail account and edited the question and it is saying peer review ,then checked i was logged in with new account ,new to stack exchange sorry about that. And i opened via gui yesterday but i need to check is that file i have opened or other.

Comment: Ah, I see. I am afraid for now there is no option to see the (a) log from yesterday, you need to run some kind of a "logger". Which is easy, but not for the past :(. Please @ping someone if a comment is meant for a specific person (else he or she will probably not notice).

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks jacob so there is no way i can see whether i opened that file yesterday.

Comment: Not unless you edited it I am afraid.

Comment: @JacobVlijm if i install GNOME then can i see yesterday activity.

Comment: You can install whatever you want, the answer still will be no.